# Standard for database connection - try/catch?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I am new to coding in Visual Studio and C#. I have my connection to my db working, and I can insert/update/delete just fine. But what if the database cannot connect one day? What kind of precautions should be coded? I think maybe a try/catch?

For example I have this code:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        //Insert text into db
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            sqlCmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Person(Name, Location, City, State) VALUES (@Name, @Location, @City, @State)");

            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EventName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = name;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = location;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = city;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2).Value = state;

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

          }
}
```

Should that code be under try? What should be under the catch? Is there any other standard to catch if a database cannot connect or if some unexpected error occurs? Thank you.

Comment: Exception handling is for unexpected situation, not being able to connect to a DB is unexpected, sure have a try catch. First determine, if you are going to try/catch in the library or let the exception bubble up to the caller, also determine if you can gracefully handle the exception and let the user work on the application.

Comment: don't always assume that `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` this will execute successfully. regardless if the connection is good and the database is up and running.. what if you had an error in the Insert statement.. I would wrap that around a `try{}catch{}` for sure and catch (`SqlException sqlEx`)

Comment: You should only catch an exception *if you can meaningfully handle it* at that point in the logic.  If, within this method, you can recover from the exception then you should catch it.  Or if you can add meaningful information to the exception then you can catch it, add the information, and re-throw.  *Catching* an exception is part of the language, but *meaningfully handling* the exception is a logical concept that only you, as the developer, can define.

Comment: You should not catch if you have nothing to do with that exception. Logging? No sir. The stack trace says it all when the exception is logged by a central error handling mechanism. You may want to catch though if you for instance want to log the parameters but then catch, and throw a new custom exception with your parameters and may be table name and command type, but please please don't forget to assign the actual exception to the InnerException. Also, if you just catch, do something and throw the same exception, please use just throw; not throw ex; to preserve the stack trace.

Comment: Good suggestions. I think I'll implement a "Try Again" button.